# Archer T3U not connecting in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.1 x86_64, kernel  5.4.0-60-generic. I'm temporarily using my phone via USB for connection.
I've recently acquired an Archer T3U USB wifi adapter, which works perfectly in windows. However, I'm having issues in getting it to work in Linux. Looking around in the forums, I've found three repositories which seem to solve most people's problems:

- https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
- https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver
- https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu

However, none of them seem to work from me. The best I can get is for it to recognize the module and show available networks, but it doesn't succeed in connecting to any. Here are the steps I took in my latest attempt (using  https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu after trying https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver):

- removed previous module

```
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/git --all
cd RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
make uninstall
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm -rf ~/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver/
sudo rmmod 88x2bu
```

- add new one

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl88x2bu
# and after taking care to remove my phone (I've seen in one of the other askubuntu threads someone say that this helped):
sudo dkms install rtl88x2bu/5.6.1
reboot
```

After rebooting, after inserting the USB module it does show up in the GUI menus, but nevers finishes to connect. Some more info:

- secure boot was disabled before I started
- lsusb does show the module:

```
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 2357:012d TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
```

- rfkill is not blocking the device:

```
5: phy5: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

- sudo lshw -class network shows this (after all the other entries for ethernet, etc):

```
*-network:2
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlxd03745fee556
       serial: d0:37:45:fe:e5:56
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

Can anybody help me with this? I have no idea what to try next, and I need this USB Wifi module to function in order to use Ubuntu for work in this machine

Answer (score 0):

https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/208022

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

I have just used above instructions from the link listed above to install T3U on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have not any credit in solving this problem. It works for me.

Comment: Tried this, but still no success. After the steps described, it lists available networks, and after a loooong time trying to connect it fails. After rebooting, the system does not detect the wifi adapter, and the module is not listed in lsmod. However, it's installed, since it shows up when I run dkms status